# Graphing a hash of dates in Rails App

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, chartkick

I have a hash that is formatted like this :

```
   @dates =  {5=>[Tue, 09 May 2017, Wed, 09 May 2018], 4=>[Sun, 09 Apr 2017], 6=>[Fri, 09 Jun 2017]}
```

It is created/sorted by month using the following:

```
@dates.group_by{|m| m.month}
```

and my goal is to graph the count for each month for example

```
 May(5) => 2 , April(4) => 1 , June(6) => 1
```

I have tried using chartkick but I am having trouble with the syntax, I have tried the following in my view, the only think that shows up is a "Loading..." text

```
<%= line_chart @dates %>
<%= line_chart @dates.count %>
```

Note upon inspecting the console i am seeing this error

```
 "Uncaught ReferenceError: Chartkick is not defined
    at user?"
```

however I have included this in my application.js and I have it in my Gemfile as well.

```
//= require Chart.bundle
//= require chartkick
```

Comment: nope which is strange, the only thing that happens is a "Loading..." text appears but no data is loaded into it